# Win10 urgent shutdown and now PC won't boot. What should I investigate next?

Tags: boot, motherboard, bios, power-supply

I have a PC that I built with the following components:

ASUS Z87-PRO

Intel Core i5 3570K 3.4 GHz

Corsair H100i cooler

EVGA GeForce 780 GTX Ti

I don't recall the RAM info. I have a SSD and a HDD as well.

The power supply is XFX Pro 850W Black Edition.

The build is about 4 years old and has run well for a long while. Basically, I was playing WoW and watching Netflix last night and Win10 showed the "we are shutting down but you have apps running well too bad" screen and then shut off.

I tried booting back up but the computer wouldn't get to the point where it outputs to the display.

Visible issues would be dust, a chassis fan in the front that lights up but is not spinning. I tried resetting the CMOS and BIOS via jumper and pulling the battery. I tried pulling the GPU and hooking the monitor up to the onboard video.

At one point, I did get the display on and it reported an issue with overclock settings at POST (I think after I reset the BIOS). I went into the BIOS and it shut down before I could actually investigate.

I tried pulling the RAM and reseating it with no effect.

No beeps to speak of. The TPU flashes through codes while booting but doesn't really settle anywhere. It has showed code 58 right before powering off but sometimes more codes show before the power off.

I'm guessing this is a fried CPU, motherboard, or power supply issue. The chassis fan, which is hooked to the water cooler, makes me wonder if there's a freakout about heat (which would be surprising). Any recommendations for further testing?

I'd be okay with replacing the motherboard and CPU, but I don't want to neglect any obvious tests first. It was weird that it didn't bluescreen and die if it's a hardware failure, unless that shutdown screen is the Win10 equivalent?

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions. Aloha.

Comment: Does letting it sit and completely cool get it to run longer? If so, it's probably a heat issue. Make sure the CPU cooling is working properly.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to test if the computer still works, i'd attempt launching ubuntu on it, since it's quick and easy to do. assuming you have access to downloading ubunto to a usb/disc... i did this before on an old computer that had a virus and would never boot. i was able to retrieve all my files back.

maybe you'll be able to re-install your os from a fresh start. could delete/format the partitions. etc...